# $K(x)$ is a simple extension of $K(u)$ and find the dimension of it

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $K$ be a field, $x$ an indeterminate, and $u=\frac{x^4}{x−1} \in K(x)$.  Prove that $K(x)$ is a simple extension of $K(u)$.  What is $[K(x) :K(u)]$?

I want to find such an $\alpha \in K(x)$ such that $K(x)=K(u)(\alpha)$. I have a really problem with even starting the solution, I am thinking that this $\alpha$ should depend on $u$ but have no idea how to find it.

Edition:

Let $x$ be indeterminate. Then, we have that $p(t)=t^4-ut+u \in K(u)[t]$ and $p(x)=x^4-ux+u=0$, so $[K(x):K(u)]=4??$ I am not sure about that what is the way to show that $K(x)$ is simple in $K(u).$

Comment: I suppose that $x4$ is a typo? You do not need to know immediately how to start the solution. The first thing is to understand the question and the context. This is what you also could write a bit more about.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is that you established a surjective ring homomorphism $K(u)[t]/(p) \rightarrow K(x)$. This is a good starting point.

It remains to show that $p$ is irreducible in $K(u)[t]$, which would imply that the quotient $K(u)[t]/(p)$ is a field, hence the above ring homomorphism must be an isomorphism, and $K(x) \simeq K(u)[t]/(p)$ is *by definition* a simple extension (and obviously of degree $4$).

To show that $p$ is irreducible, there are many possible ways. The following is a more general result:

> Proposition: Let $f, g \in K[t]$ be coprime polynomials. Then the polynomial $f + ug \in K(u)[t]$ is irreducible.

Proof: It is clear that $f + ug$, as a polynomial in $K[u][t]$, is irreducible, since it has degree $1$ in $u$, hence in any factorization $f + ug = pq$, one of $p$ and $q$ (say $p$) must have degree $0$ in $u$, i.e. is in fact a polynomial in $t$. It then follows that $p$ is a common factor of $f$ and $g$, which must be a constant.

The result then follows from [Gauss's lemma for UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)#Statements_for_unique_factorization_domains).